# What are valid BIP32 version bytes in descriptors & optional key origin defaults?

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, output-script-descriptors

BIP49 & BIP84 defined different BIP32 version bytes so that serialized xpubs start with ypub/zpub/upub/vpub.

This led to some incompatibility in the past with wallets and libraries that used (or didn't) those version bytes.

- Do descriptors finally get rid of different version bytes?
- For example, is `wpkh([d34db33f/84'/0'/0']zpub...)` not valid? (note the **zpub** string)
- Also, since [key origin information is optional in descriptors](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/descriptors.md#reference), are there default derivation paths or are they supposed to be undefined?

  For example, in an extended descriptor without optional key origin such as this one: `wpkh(xpub...)`, can we assume its derivation path starts from `84'/...`?

  Or for `wsh(pkh(xpub...))` is it `49'/...`? Or should we not assume that?